# I cannot post data - Django

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am currently building a Django React app and I want the users to be able to create an instance of a model (listing) from the frontend.
I was trying to build the backend, but when I try the url: http://localhost:8000/api/listings/create on Postman I get an error : "detail":"Method "POST" not allowed."

Also, if I use "/listings/admin/create" instead, I do not get this error.

**My model :**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
        
  artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150)   
  photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='photos/default.jpg') 
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**My view :**

```
class CreateListingView(APIView):  
  parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
  queryset = Listing.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ListingSerializer

  def post(self, request, format=None):
    print(request.data)
    serializer = ListingSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
      return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**My app Urls :**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListingsView, ListingView, SearchView,CreateListingView

app_name = 'listings'

urlpatterns = [
path('', ListingsView.as_view(),name='listings'),
path('search', SearchView.as_view(),name='listingssearc'),
path('<slug>', ListingView.as_view(),name='listingsdetails'),
path('create', CreateListingView.as_view(),name='listingscreate')
]
```

**My project urls :**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
path('api/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
path('api/artists/', include('artists.urls')),
path('api/listings/', include('listings.urls', namespace='listings')),
path('api/contact/', include('contact.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

So what did I do wrong? I don't understand why I get a 405 error.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: which url gives you a 405 ?

Comment: It's http://localhost:8000/api/listings/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url-pattern is tried one line after the other.

in your urlpatterns you catch the call to "create" in  the line before as slug:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', ListingsView.as_view(),name='listings'),
path('search', SearchView.as_view(),name='listingssearc'),
path('<slug>', ListingView.as_view(),name='listingsdetails'),
path('create', CreateListingView.as_view(),name='listingscreate')
]
```

so it is going to listingsdetails which obviously does not allow post requests.

change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', ListingsView.as_view(),name='listings'),
path('search', SearchView.as_view(),name='listingssearc'),
path('create', CreateListingView.as_view(),name='listingscreate'),
path('<slug>', ListingView.as_view(),name='listingsdetails')
]
```

then it is only catched by the last line if it has a slug that is not search or create.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
class CreateListingView(APIView):  
  def post(self, request, format=None):
    print(request.data)
    serializer = ListingSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
      return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For reference please see this drf [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this, but saddly it is not working.

Comment: try with generic view

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing

`class CreateListingView(APIView):`
to
`class CreateListingView(generics.ListCreateAPIView)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that also but I still got no luck !